# Brew Install Trouble

Tags: terminal, homebrew, minikube

I'm struggling to brew install minikube. I don't have any version, but need an older version. I'm trying the familiar way, but get an error:

```
~ brew install minikube@1.18.1
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "minikube@1.18.1".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I've tried to do a bit of homework, but still errors:

```
~ brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8d37c361ee69503961a3010e7896f6ecf8d3a059/Formula/minikube.rb
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 16 formulae.

Traceback (most recent call last):
`brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.: Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of minikube formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported!  (UsageError)
`brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.: Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of minikube formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported!  (UsageError)
```

This must be elementary, but I can't seem to figure this out :(

Answer (score 4):

Before running:

```
brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8d37c361ee69503961a3010e7896f6ecf8d3a059/Formula/minikube.rb
```

you should execute:

```
brew unlink minikube
```

That way you will remove the old minikube links and link the newly installed binary.

---

If that's still not working than try running:

```
wget https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8d37c361ee69503961a3010e7896f6ecf8d3a059/Formula/minikube.rb
```

followed by:

```
brew install --HEAD -s minikube.rb
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice. It worked when I installed the binary manually.

Answer (score 4):

`$brew update-reset`

This helped me with the error.

Answer (score 2):

Brew only does creates separate versions for certain formula, and its mostly only the larger ones where they might provide different versions due to backward compatibility and stuff.
You might have some luck with the answers in this question [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula).

Answer (score 1):

I think first you can try to run 'brew install minikube' only, see if you can successfully install it or not. If no error then it's probably your version issue. If still has Error then that might be your local home-brew issues, then you can Try to run 'brew doctor', based on the warning and Error info search in stackoverflow you probably will find out the answer.